# Initializing class properties

Tags: php, php-7.4

I need to initialize some properties in my class. I don't use constructor, only set methods.

```
<?php

namespace Task;

class Log {
  private $_views = null;
  private $_urls = null;
  private $_traffic = null;

  /**
   * @param int $count
   */
  public function setViewCount(int $count) {
    $this->$_views = $count;
  }

  /**
   * @return int
   */
  public function getViewCount() {
    return $this->$_views;
  }

  /**
   * @param int $count
   */
  public function setUrlCount(int $count) {
    $this->$_urls = $count;
  }

  /**
   * @return int
   */
  public function getUrlCount() {
    return $this->$_urls;
  }

  /**
   * @param int $trafficData
   */
  public function setTraffic(int $trafficData) {
    $this->$_traffic = $trafficData;
  }

  /**
   * @return int
   */
  public function getTraffic() {
    return $this->$_traffic;
  }
}

?>
```

Then I try to set values to properties and save it to associative array.

```
<?php

require 'Log.php';

use Task;

$log = new Task\Log();
$log->setViewCount(44);
$log->setUrlCount(55);
$log->setTraffic(99999);

$res = array("views" => $log->getViewCount(), "urls" => $log->getUrlCount(), "traffic" => $log->getTraffic());
echo json_encode($res);
?>
```

After encoding to json I see that any element of array has last value I set to object. In this example last is 99999 for `Traffic` so I got `{"views":99999,"urls":99999,"traffic":99999}`. What's the reason of such behaviour and how can I get correct values in each element of array?

Comment: Don't suppress warnings and you'll see exactly what the problem is. You have `$this->$_views` but you want `$this->_views`. You're inadvertently creating an empty [variable variable](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$this->$_views` this accesses not the field named `_views` but a field with the name stored in variable `$_views`.

Since you have no such variable the name assumed empty, thus the same name for each of setters or getters.

In short: you need to remove `$` after `->`:

```
  $this->_urls = $count;
```

etc.

Comment: Thanks I was confused with this. I thought double `$` is the same cause I also tried to check properties with `$` and without and that gave different results.